# SavedInstance Scroll position for gridView is not working

Tags: android, gridview

This is my code to save the gridview scroll state. But it is not retrieved in the restore instance. Only this step is required for my project to pass.

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, null);

        if (savedInstance != null) {
            MovieTask.mProgressDialog.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstance);
            gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(savedInstance.getInt("scroll"));
       }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MovieTask.mProgressDialog.onSaveInstanceState();
        savedInstanceState.putInt("scroll",gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Here is the AsyncTask code. Where I am initializing the gridview.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    String categoryType = preferences.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_key_category) ,mContext.getString(R.string.pref_category_default_value));
    if(categoryType.equals(Constants.TOP_RATED_KEY)){
        Category = Constants.TOP_RATED_KEY;
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Top Rated Movies");
    } else if (categoryType.equals(Constants.POPULARITY_KEY)){
        Category = Constants.POPULARITY_KEY;
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Popular Movies");

    }
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(Constants.MOVIE_URL + Category + Constants.API_KEY);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(url));

        // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // Nothing to do.
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
            return null;
        }
        movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
        // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
        // to parse it.
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        return getMovieDataFromJson(movieJsonStr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
    if(result != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        if(NetworkUtility.isOnline(mContext)){

            List<Model> favoriteMovie = Model.listAll(Model.class);
            MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mContext, favoriteMovie, new MovieAdapter.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(String title, String poster, String plot, double ratings, String release, long id) {
                    if (MainActivity.mTwoPane) {
                        ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, DetailsFragment.newInstance(title, poster, plot, ratings, release, id))
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title", title);
                        intent.putExtra("poster", poster);
                        intent.putExtra("plot",plot);
                        intent.putExtra("ratings", ratings);
                        intent.putExtra("release", release);
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

            });
            MoviesFragment.gridView = (GridView) MoviesFragment.rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            MoviesFragment.gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
            int index = MoviesFragment.gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            MoviesFragment.gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Please Enable Internet Services",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where/ how do you declare/initialize "gridView" ?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I am intialising the gridView in my AsyncTask in PostExecute method.

Comment: Well, if your problem persists consider adding some code (e.g. code for starting the AsyncTask/ code of AsyncTask)  Just guessing isn't really fun.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have added the AsyncTask Code please do check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use to shared preference  Otherway  try it

`gridView.setSelection(savedInstance.getInt("scroll"))`

Comment: In my opinion   remove  savedInstance.getInt("scroll")   use to shared preference

Answer (score 0):

Do you know when `onSaveInstanceState`  and `onRestoreInstanceState`will be called. If you manually close the activity, for example hit back, the **savedInstance** will always be null.

I think you are looking for sharedPreference to store the **scroll position**

Answer (score 0):

At the following point during the execution of `onCreateView()`, it looks like the `AsyncTask` has been started (at least you're accessing `MovieTask.mProgressDialog` and nothing crashes, so I think `onPreExecute()` has finished successfully).

```
MovieTask.mProgressDialog.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstance);
gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(savedInstance.getInt("scroll"));
```

If `onPostExecute()` runs after these lines are executed, then the following statements will simply set the scroll position to the beginning of the content:

```
MoviesFragment.gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
int index = MoviesFragment.gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
MoviesFragment.gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
```

This happens because `movieAdapter`is created from scratch and the `GridView` is informed that from now on the content to display will be provided by this adapter. So the usual thing happens: `getCount()` is called, the `GridView` is filled from the beginning and the scroll position is set to the beginning as well.

To get the desired scroll position, you can introduce a variable

```
int lastScrollPosition = -1;
```

in `MovieTask`. Set the value to the desired position in `onCreateView()` if the `savedInstanceState != null`

```
int index = savedInstance.getInt("scroll", -1);   
// case 1: AsyncTask still busy
MovieTask.lastScrollPosition = index;
// case 2: AsyncTask already finished
if (index >= 0)
{
    // seems from the source of AbsListView = parent of GridView
    // that there will be no crash if index is too big
    MoviesFragment.gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
}
```

and read it in `onPostExecute()`:

```
if (lastScrollPosition >= 0 and lastScrollPosition < movieAdapter.getCount())
{
    MoviesFragment.gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastScrollPosition);    
}
```

This way, the scroll position will be used if possible.

Comment: What should I do to restore the scroll position?